# Zero mean constraint for correlations with the Mobius function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion

An aspect of my research has lead me to believe that I need to distinguish between those bounded functions $\xi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which correlate with the Mobius function $\mu(n)$, i.e. have the property that
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\xi(n)\neq o(x),$$ according as to whether $$\sum_{n\leq x}\xi(n)= o(x)$$ or not.

I believe this is necessary in order to avoid certain cases: for example, if one fixes a square free  natural number $k>1$ and takes $\xi(n)=1$ for $n\neq mk$ and $\xi(mk)=\mu(m)$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\xi(n)\sim \frac{6\mu(k)}{\pi^2\phi(k)}$$ and $$\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\xi(n)\sim 1-\frac{1}{k}.$$
Of course such cases are in some sense artificial, none-the-less it seems incomplete to consider the notion of Mobius correlation without a zero mean constraint---at least because $\mu(n)$ itself has zero mean.

> For this reason I would like to ask about the following: How are these cases distinguished when considering sums of the form $$\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)\xi(n)$$ in the context of topological dynamics, or; as the inverse Mellin transform of a Dirichlet series with coefficients $\mu(n)\xi(n)$?
>
> To put it another way, I would like to know where the mean-value of $\xi$ comes into play when considering sums of this form, and if there a qualitative
> relation/some expression you use in which the mean value of $\xi$ appears explicitly?

Comment: Since [$\sum_{n < x} \mu(n) = \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\zeta'(\rho) \rho} + O(1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function), what comes into play is $\sum_{n < x}(\xi(n)-\xi(n-1)) n^{\rho}$ and hence $\sum_{n < x} \xi(n) n^{\rho-1}$ where $\rho$ are the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$. Now you probably have some particular sequences $\xi(n)$ in mind (the Dirichlet characters ?)

Comment: @user1952009 My interest is in general bounded complex valued sequences. I believe the formula you have stated requires RH. Please would you explain what you have said in a little more detail?